# Is Google Drive RealTime API for Android?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Does Google Drive RealTime API still not support Android? I did it using JavaScript but want to use it in Android. I don't think it does exist cause no official blogs say that and it doesn't even appear on the [Developers site](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/). Is there any alternative for these purpose? Or I need to just do it all myself till Google announces anything? And if so can you please suggest me should I put everything on my server and send it to devices using [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html); or should I use [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/)?

A very similar question here: [StackOverflow Question](http://goo.gl/tD4Uk). But I even found these links saying it does [Link 1](http://www.intellectsoft.co.uk/blog/google-drive-realtime-api/), [Link 2](http://androidheadlines.com/2013/03/latest-google-drive-api-allows-third-party-apps-to-make-use-of-the-realtime-synch-features.html). So any updates?
Please help thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently Realtime API does not support Android, sorry.

BUT! Google are working on this, and it should be available quite soon. Google are excited about the possibility of users collaborating simultaneously between web and mobile apps in real time. That is going to rock!

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! We are waiting too! Hope it comes soon...:)

Comment: Can you confirm that there is still no Andorid API?